# Java Text Box Validation Using Double.parseDouble()

Tags: java, validation, double

I have a Swing `JTextBox` that basically will hold a double.

I find that using:

```
  Double.parseDouble(this.myTB.getText());
```

will throw an exception (and thus program is terminated) whenever `Double.parseDouble()` gets invalid input.

My question: is there an easy way to NOT throw an exception, and instead return an integer `(-1)` saying that parseDouble() failed?

I am trying to make a popup for the user saying he or she's data field is invalid.

Thanks

---

EDIT:

Thanks lol.  How could I forget about catching exceptions? it's been a long day!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The best way to handle this is by using a try/catch block.

```
try {
    return Double.parseDouble(this.myTB.getText());
} catch (NumberFormatException e) {
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog("Oops");
    return -1;
}
```

The `JOptionPane` is a great way to display warning messages to users.

Answer (score 0):

Catch the `NumberFormatException`, and return your desired error value (or take some other action from within the catch clause).

```
double value = -1;
try {
    value =  Double.parseDouble(this.myTB.getText());
} catch (NumberFormatException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
return value;
```

Comment: Thanks! However, it seems as though that even after we catch the exception ... it still shows in the console output.  Is there anyway to supress the exception after it has been caught?

Comment: removing the `e.printStackTrace();` will prevent the exception from showing on the console.

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
try{
    return Double.parseDouble(this.myTB.getText());
   } catch(NumberFormatException e) {
       return -1;
   }
```